# Permutation of a word with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

```
how many distinct arrangements there are of the word MATEMATICA so that: 
-1)there are two consecutive M
-2)there aren't consecutive vowel
-3)both of the precedent conditions are true;
```

For the n° 1: writing the word as MMXXXXXXXX there are $\frac{8!}{3!2!}$ distinct permutation of the X's part and there are 9 permutation of the block MM so there're $\frac{8!}{3!2!} * 9 = 30240$ permutation in which there's the M's are consecutive.

For n°2: writing the word as XMXTXMXTXCX the X's are the n° of the vowel + a blank space
there are $6! = 720$ permutation of the X's but the blank space cannot be inside the word so 
$720 - 4 = 716$ permutation.
Now,i'm not sure I've done it right (i don't have the solution) and I don't know how to do the n° 3

Comment: I think you made a fencepost error. For part 1, aren't there $9$ places that the MM can go, not $8$?

Comment: You're right...fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use X instead of MM, and count the number of permutations of AAACEITTX instead:

   $\binom93\cdot\binom61\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom32\cdot\binom11=30240$
2. Put AAAEI in the odd places and CMMTT in the even places, and then vice versa:

   $\binom53\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom22\cdot2=1200$
3. Put AAAEI in the odd places and CXTT in the even places:

   $\binom53\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom22=240$

Comment: You left out the C in part one. For part 3, you effectively have 4 consonants and 5 vowels, so you could still have VCVCVCVCV. You need to consider the possibility of a double-consonant in part 2, as well.

Comment: @KSmarts: Yep, thanks...

Comment: What is the notation you're using? why you write the permutation as a multiplication of combination instead of writing with factorial?

Comment: @Azazel: $\binom{n}{k}$, also expressed as **"$n$ over $k$"** or as **"choose $k$ out of $n$"**, is equivalent to $\frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!}$. So in essence, I **am** using factorial in this answer.

Comment: I know the "n over k" notation,but I thought it was only used in combination problem. I understood that what  you wrote is equal to the permutation notation,but i want just understand why you wrote the answer in this way.
I had un-accept the answer because I wanted to wait for your answer :)

Comment: @Azazel: There is typically more than one way for solving this type of problems. I tend to use "choose" because it's a more intuitive way for me to approach these problems.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This only applies for part 3.

For 1, it is useful to think of the two "M"s as one entity, since they must be together. "MATEMATICA" has 10 letters, so if you think of the two "M"s together as a single letter, you have 9 letters, meaning there are \frac{9!}{2!}{3!} valid combinations (after eliminating the double-counting from "T" and "A")

This should drastically simplify part 2. A useful observation for 2 is that there are 5 vowels in 9 letters (remembering that two M's are treated as one letter), meaning the odd-places must have vowels and even-places must have consonants.

Comment: For part 2, there are 10 letters. That doesn't change a lot, just assume odd-places have vowels and evens have consonants and solve, then multiply by 2. Also, on the first part, you still need to consider duplicate letters, which brings you very close to the OP's solution.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken. The extra consonant does change things, as you could have one double-consonant between two vowels and still be able to keep all the vowels separate.

Comment: Whoops, I should have mentioned that this was for part 3 only. Edited.